# Update features based on multiple GetParameterAsText

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, python-script-tool, parameters

I am trying to figure out how to update feature attributes by user input parameters (`GetParameterAsText`). Current script the user inputs a `arcpy.GetParameterAsText(can be multiple)` then there is a second `arcpy.GetParameterAsText(this can also be multiple)`. I need to be able to apply the secondary `arcpy.GetParameterAsText` to each of the first `arcpy.GetParameterAsText`.

In the table below show what I have and what I need.

How can I accomplish this?

[image]

Here is my current code.

```
lyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "TAXLOTS")[0]

#Parcel numbers
values = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) # parcel numbers
fieldName = "PIN"
values = values.split(";")  # split values into list
values = ["'{0}'".format(v) for v in values] # add single quotes
whereClause = "{0} IN ({1})".format(fieldName, ",".join(values))
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(lyr, "NEW_SELECTION", whereClause)

#selects the parcel numbers and creates Subject property
if int(arcpy.GetCount_management("TAXLOTS").getOutput(0)) > 0:
   arcpy.Select_analysis("TAXLOTS", "SUBJECT")
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("TAXLOTS", "CLEAR_SELECTION")

#AddsPermitNumber
Casenum = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2) #permit numbers
SP = "SUBJECT"
#Splt = str(Casenum.split(";"))
#arcpy.AddMessage("Case ={0}".format(Splt))

arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(SP, "INTERSECT", SP, "", "NEW_SELECTION")
if int(arcpy.GetCount_management("TAXLOTS").getOutput(0)) > 0:
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(SP, "PermitNo", '"' + Casenum +'"', "PYTHON_9.3") #"!{0}!".format(values)

args = [arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)for i in range(arcpy.GetArgumentCount())]
#pCount = arcpy.GetArgumentCount(1)

if args == 2: #
    dsc = arcpy.Describe(SP)
    fields = dsc.fields
    #out_fields = [dsc.OIDFieldName]
    fieldnames = [field.name for field in fields]

    #lstFields = [field.name for field in fields]

    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(SP,fieldnames) as sCur:
       with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(SP,fieldnames) as iCur:
          for row in sCur:
              iCur.insertRow(row)
else:
    pass
```

Comment: Be sure to add your code. What have you tried?

Comment: As @Encomium suggests, we can't give specific advice on how to change your code without some sample code to start with.  However, generally, you are likely looking at a need to take the "Permit No" values and use `.split(";")` on them to get them as a list instead of a string. Then use a for loop to iterate over each of those values.  But again, specific code modification suggestions would have to be based on your specific code.

Comment: To compliment Encomium and John, don't put up code with fake paths as maybe the problem is in the very thing people for some reason try to hide.. It's very irritating especially as they have come for help and then don't give you the full storey.

Comment: Sorry about that.

Comment: What happens when you run the code that you have presented?

Comment: All of he features that are provided by arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) get attributes  "PermitNum" filed with "MC2021-0002:CD2021-005" or what ever is provided in GetParameterAsText(1) but it's all combined with a ":".

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Comment: Hard to believe no one has came across this... Any ideas, code or examples would be gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One way to resolve this would be to use nested for loops on your input parameters.  I've used your variable names, but stripped the code down just to deliver the output you've highlighted in the question.  The output is a list of lists.

```
values = "12345;12346;12347" #arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
Casenum = "MCS021-0002;CD2021-0005" #arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)

records = []
for permit in Casenum.split(";"):
    for pin in values.split(";"):
        records.append([pin, permit])
        # create function here to select TAXLOTS and calculate the permit number

for a in records:
    print(a)
```

Code output:

```
['12345', 'MCS021-0002']
['12346', 'MCS021-0002']
['12347', 'MCS021-0002']
['12345', 'CD2021-0005']
['12346', 'CD2021-0005']
['12347', 'CD2021-0005']
```

You will need to rework your logic around the selection of TAXLOTS and calculation of the permit number to get the final output you're after.  Perhaps create an empty SUBJECT layer first (using TAXLOTS as a template) and then use an Insert cursor within the nested for loops.